# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - abi-coder

Tags: web3js, truffle, infura, solc, abi

I'm creating a simple voting contract.
It is deployed with truffle and infura.

This is the contract code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Voter {
    struct OptionPos {
        uint pos;
        bool exists;
    }

    uint[] public votes;
    string[] public options;
    mapping (address => bool) hasVoted;
    mapping (string => OptionPos) posOfOption;
    bool votingStarted;

    function addOption(string memory option) public {
        require(!votingStarted);
        options.push(option);
    }

    function startVoting() public {
        require(!votingStarted);
        votes.length = options.length;

        for (uint i = 0; i< options.length; i++) {
            OptionPos memory optionPos = OptionPos(i, true);
            posOfOption[options[i]] = optionPos;
        }
        votingStarted = true;
    }

    function vote(uint option) public {
        require(0<=option && option< options.length, "Invalid option");
        require(!hasVoted[msg.sender], "Account has already voted");

        votes[option] = votes[option]+1;
        hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function vote(string memory optionName) public {
        require(!hasVoted[msg.sender], "Account has already voted");
        OptionPos memory optionPos = posOfOption[optionName];
        require(optionPos.exists, "Option does not exist");

        votes[optionPos.pos] = votes[optionPos.pos]+1;
        hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function getVotes() public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        return votes;
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to run this node.js script:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import 'dotenv/config';
import HDWalletProvider from 'truffle-hdwallet-provider';

const { ACCOUNT, VOTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS } = process.env;


async function sendTransaction() {
  const ethprovider = new HDWalletProvider(
    process.env.MNEMONIC,
    process.env.PROVIDER
  );
  let web3 = new Web3('https://');
  web3.setProvider(ethprovider);
  let { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './build/contracts/Voter.json')));

  let voter = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, VOTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

  console.log('Adding option tea');
  let res = await voter.methods.addOption('tea').call({ from: ACCOUNT });
  console.log(res);
  console.log('Adding option coffee');
  res = await voter.methods.addOption('coffee').call({ from: ACCOUNT });
  console.log(res);

  console.log('Start voting');
  await voter.methods.startVoting().call({ from: ACCOUNT, gas: 4500000 });

  console.log('Voting');
  res = await voter.methods['vote(uint256)'](1).call({ from: ACCOUNT, gas: 4500000 });
  console.log(res);

  console.log('getVotes');
  res = await voter.methods.getVotes().call({ from: ACCOUNT, gas: 4500000 })
  console.log(res);
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await sendTransaction();
    console.log('successfully voted');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

But I get the error:

```
Adding option tea
null
Adding option coffee
null
Start voting
Voting
Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
        at getParamCoder (/Users/username/solidity-project/node_modules/ethers/utils/abi-coder.js:866:39)
```

I'm using web3 1.0.0-beta.55 and truffle 5.0.26.
I managed to avoid this issue by adding a return type `uint` to `vote` function and returning an integer. But I'm trying to fix it without adding return type.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget to call method (smart contract function) after `methods` in `res = await voter.methods['vote(uint256)'](1).call({ from: ACCOUNT, gas: 4500000 });` @Dominik

Comment: No. `methods['vote(uint256)']` is selecting a method vote with parameter uint256 and `(1)` is a method call. I also tried with  voter.methods.vote(0), but still get the same output. @Harsh

Comment: Try using `send` instead of `call` as call is to call a function (which does not change the state of a contract) where as send is used to change the state of a smart contract. Use this link [https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call] for reference. @Dominik

Comment: @Harsh
Yes, that did the trick! Thanks!
I also needed to add `{ transactionConfirmationBlocks: 3 }` parameter into my contract initialization in order to `.send` work with await. Otherwise, it would just hang.
So the voter initialization now looks like this: `const voter = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, VOTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, { transactionConfirmationBlocks: 3 })`

Comment: Cool. Good to here that. :)